# Variable downtime duration and inter-ocurrence in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have an anylogic model using the process modeling library and there a downtime linked to a resource pool. I would like the values of my downtime "Total time between ocurrences" and "Task duration" to vary based on a checkbox that can be clicked on during the model running. For example: if checkbox is not clicked, I want the downtime to last 5m, but to last 10m if it is clicked.

I have tried to use variables and functions to set up these values, but although the variables do update during the model run (when the checkbox is clicked), the downtime values do not change. It looks like they are defined once at the model start and never again updated. Is there a way I could update it? I have tried as well through events that use embebbed functions from the downtime, but I could not find any :(

Some more details (images):

Model:

[image: Model]

Service with the associated resource pool:

[image: Service with the associated resource pool]

Resource Pool associated to the Downtime:

[image: Resource Pool associated to the Downtime]

Downtime setup where I attempt to use the variables or functions:

[image: Downtime setup where I attempt to use the variables or functions]

Checkbox where I update the variables value:

[image: Checkbox where I update the variables value]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a simple conditional statement as:
[image]

Assuming you have a checkbox `myCheckbox` next to the downtime block

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it does not work :( The model seems still to check value of the myCheckbox only in the beginning. So my downtimes are not changing when I click on the Checkbox. Is there maybe any other possibility? Thank you :)